# Android Google Map Blank Screen

Tags: android

I am new to android and facing a problem with maps.In my application, I can see the box containing the map but map is showing nothing except white grid ,I saw some previous stackoverflow answers to the same problem but still not able to solve the issue.Please help me.Thanks.

My manifest file contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
    </uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.AIzaSyDhp2d1pq1R7qg0p4BjqdTCwaRuuXckTJU"
        android:value="AIzaSyDhp2d1pq1R7qg0p4BjqdTCwaRuuXckTJU"/>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

And my layout activity file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:apiKey="AIzaSyDhp2d1pq1R7qg0p4BjqdTCwaRuuXckTJU"
          android:id="@+id/mapdata"
          />
</LinearLayout>
```

I got this key from unix command

```
sau@sau-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin$ ./keytool 
-list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore /home/sau/.android/debug.keystore 
-storepass android -keypass android androiddebugkey, 11 Oct, 2014, PrivateKeyEntry, 

Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 32:6D:54:16:96:66:82:39:EC:4C:5B:3A:16:79:
B3:96:EF:77:9D:C2
```

I used this sha1 to get the key AIzaSyDhp2d1pq1R7qg0p4BjqdTCwaRuuXckTJU,

```
    Key for Android apps (with certificates)
    API key:    
    AIzaSyDhp2d1pq1R7qg0p4BjqdTCwaRuuXckTJU
    Android apps:   
    32:6D:54:16:96:66:82:39:EC:4C:5B:3A:16:79:B3:96:EF:77:9D:C2;com.example.maps
    Activated on:   Oct 30, 2014 12:05 AM
    Activated by:   saurabh.saluja2013@gmail.com – you
```

what am I doing wrong??

Comment: mapview is oldone... try to use mapfragment

Comment: Okay :-), Can you provide me any link where I can get the syntax to use mapfragment?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: Check your internet connection

Answer (score 0):

Your manifesto should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.errorpoint.findlocation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.errorpoint.findlocation.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.errorpoint.findlocation.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Key goes here" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**xml file**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**See my full example in Github;** [Link](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apis/tree/master/FindLocation)